# Get HTML input type

Tags: 8

I need to get all HTML field types from article content type.
I try with:

```
  $entity_type = 'node';
  $bundle = $value;
  $form_mode = 'default';

  $form_display = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('entity_form_display')
    ->load($entity_type . '.' . $bundle . '.' . $form_mode);

  $definitions = $form_display->get('fieldDefinitions');

  $key_names = array_keys($definitions);
  foreach ($key_names as $key_name) {
    $specific_widget_type = $form_display->getComponent($key_name);
    $all_fields [$bundle][$key_name] = $specific_widget_type['type'];
  }
```

And I get:

```
"langcode": "language_select",
"revision_log": "string_textarea",
"status": "boolean_checkbox",
"title": "string_textfield",
```

... etc

A need to get clean HTML input types. like textarea, checkbox... Is there any way to get that?

Comment: There isn't one built in, but you could easily maintain your own mapping and query that when you need it

Comment: Manually map it?

Comment: Yeah in an array or whatever. The widget ID is completely arbitrary, and while core seems to be following a convention with the naming (HTML element name last in the snake case), it's not documented anywhere that I can see. So you should err on the side of caution IMO